# Error while builder loading in kivy: Invalid indentation, must be a multiple of "n" spaces

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I've been working on a kivy app and was having some trouble with Builder loading some kv language, the code crashes when I run it.

**Error message:**

```
   File "C:\Users\areef\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\venev2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 566, in parse_level
     raise ParserException(self, ln,
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 3:
 ...
       1:Screen:
       2:        FloatLayout:
 >>    3:            Button:
       4:                text: "It works!"
       5:                pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.7}
 ...
 Invalid indentation, must be a multiple of 8 spaces
```

**Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """Screen:
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: "It works!"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.7}
                text_size: self.size
        """


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

What am I doing wrong, can someone help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a triple quoted string, the leading spaces of each line are part of the string. The first indentation in your `cube` string is 20 spaces, so all the indentation is expected to be multiples of that. To fix that problem, just eliminate all those extra spaces. Try something like:

```
        cube = """
Label:
    text:"Side:"
    pos_hint: {"x":1.1, "y":0.7}
    text_size: self.size
Label:
    text:"Volume:"     
    .
    .
    .
```

Where the `Labels` are at zero indentation. That will solve the error you are seeing, and another error (unrelated to formatting) will appear.